# combine outputs of two queries group by a common field

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to combine the results of these two queries:

```
SELECT odate, 
       Count(odate), 
       Sum(dur) 
FROM   table1 t1 
GROUP  BY odate 
ORDER  BY odate; 

SELECT cdate, 
       Count(cdate), 
       Sum(dur) 
FROM   table2 t2 
GROUP  BY cdate 
ORDER  BY cdate;
```

and get something like this as a result:

```
odate,t1.count(odate),t2.sum(dur),t2.count(cdate),t2.sum(dur) order by odate
```

how to do that?

I get an error when I run this one:

```
select odate,count(odate),sum(dur) 
from table1 t1 
group by odate 
order by odate 
union 
select cdate,count(cdate),sum(dur) 
from table2 t2 
group by cdate 
order by cdate;
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this one: select odate,count(odate),sum(dur) from table1 t1 group by odate order by odate union
select cdate,count(cdate),sum(dur) from table2 t2 group by cdate order by cdate;

Comment: If you get an error, include the error message in the question.

Comment: @peterm you are right, I didn't have enough reputation to do that. I just gain the privilege and I'm going to vote up the answers.

Comment: @Narges Great! FYI you can **always** accept the answer to your question no matter what is your reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your desired result you need a `JOIN` rather then a `UNION`. You can do it like this

```
select coalesce(odate, cdate) odate, count1, sum1, count2, sum2
  from
(
  select odate, count(odate) count1, sum(dur) sum1
    from table1
   group by odate
) t1 full join
(
  select cdate, count(cdate) count2, sum(dur) sum2
    from table2
   group by cdate
) t2
    on t1.odate = t2.cdate
 order by odate;
```

Sample output:

```
|                          ODATE | COUNT1 |   SUM1 | COUNT2 |   SUM2 |
|--------------------------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      2 |     30 |      2 |     30 |
| January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |     30 | (null) | (null) |
| January, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |      1 |     30 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2087c/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a UNION statement. Basically, you take the two queries and tell SQL that they can be joined together. 
the simplest (if all the fields are the same data type) would be something like:

```
select odate,count(odate),sum(dur) from table1 t1 group by odate
UNION
(select cdate,count(cdate),sum(dur) from table2 t2 group by cdate)
ORDER BY odate;
```

Edit: your error is in where you put the ORDER BY statement. There's no point to order inside the UNION in most cases anyways.
For more information see:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select odate,count(odate),sum(dur) 
from table1 t1 
group by odate
union 
select cdate AS odate,count(cdate),sum(dur) 
from table2 t2 
group by cdate 
order by odate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Union operator
Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union. The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns from two tables.
The following are basic rules for combining the result sets of two queries by using UNION:

The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.

The data types must be compatible.

```
select odate,count(odate),sum(dur) from table1 t1 group by odate union
(select cdate,count(cdate),sum(dur) from table2 t2 group by cdate)
ORDER BY odate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename your date in the second part of your union and place the order clause at the end of your statement :

```
select odate
  ,COUNT(odate)
  ,SUM(dur) 
FROM table1  
GROUP BY odate 
UNION
SELECT cdate odate
  ,COUNT(cdate)
  ,SUM(dur) 
FROM table2  
GROUP BY cdate 
ORDER BY odate
```